When rendering an animation one light doesn't render, it does whoever show in the viewport render

When I render this scene it looks great in the cycles preview but when I render the animation the keylight doesn't render at all. The settings are the same as all the other lights.
I did however animate it form side to side.

Maybe try Eevee?

Hello could you please share your file? Remove all the objects that you don't want to share, and use a platform like workupload for example

Thanks for getting back so fast, here's the scene. Let's hope you can find something, the scene is super simple.
https://workupload.com/file/S7m3RCxXNLU

Your file makes my Blender crash but maybe disable Cube.011 for render:


Man this is embarassing, that did the trick. There was a hidden wall that only showed when rendering the final animation. I worked in 3D for over 6 years in Maya and now I'm switching to Blender. Thanks for the help!
